Why RandomForestRegressor.score() return a coefficient of determination?
In ScikitLearn's method RandomForestRegressor.score(X, y), the coefficient of determination R_2 is returned as a metric of the quality of the model.
However, as I understand, the coefficient of determination apply only for linear model, and a random forest is far from a linear model.
So, why does RandomForestRegressor.score() return a coefficient of determination, and should it never be used?

Wikipedia:

the coefficient of determination, denoted $R^2$ or $r^2$ and pronounced "R squared", is the proportion of the variation in the dependent variable that is predictable from the independent variable(s).

The concept of "explained variation" makes perfect sense for any model that allows calculating fitted values, so in particular it can be used for a Random Forest. It is not limited to linear models.
